# Schema generated from WCF web service and ASMX are different

Tags: xml, wcf, web-services, xsd, schema

I have the following class

```
[Serializable()]  
[XmlType(AnonymousType=true)][XmlRoot(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]  
public class Test  
{  
   [XmlAttribute()]  
   public string Prop { get; set; }  

   public string Another { get; set; }  
}
```

I used this class in both a WCF web service (SVC) and an ASMX web service and I'm expecting to get a SOAP body which are consistent for both ASMX and SVC where the "Prop" property is an attribute. Also, I tried adding a service and web reference to both SVC and ASMX and here's how the XSDs looked like:

1. Service Reference to SVC: Did not create XmlAttribute attribute for Test.Prop property
2. Service Reference to ASMX: Created XmlAttribute attribute for Test.Prop property
3. Web Reference to SVC: Created XmlElement for Test.Prop property
4. Web Reference to ASMX: Created XmlAttribute attribute for Test.Prop property

My question is why are the generated XSDs and therefore SOAP XMLs not consisted? I know this does not matter as both methods worked regardless of the generated schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF uses the DataContract serializer by default, which is different from the XmlSerializer that ASMX uses. Therefore, the XSD generated will vary, too - the DataCOntract serializer e.g. doesn't support XML attributes (for speed reasons).

Check out Dan Rigsby's excellent [blog post comparing the two serializers](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/), and Aaron Skonnard's MSDN Magazine article [Serialization in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx) for more details.